# sed ack search / replace line break with string

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I have looked into a few SO threads, non of which have helped my specific situation.

I am trying to update a `PHP` app that I took over from php 5.6 to php 8.0

With that said there are MANY instances that look like:

```
<?
echo ...
function
```

I need to find all cases where `<?` is followed **directly by a newline**
 and replace it with `<?php(newline)`

Per the SO posts I've read .. I think I am coming close with the following:

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/\<\?\n/\<\?php\n/g" {} \;
```

I think I am close .. But I can't figure out why it won't replace `<?\n` with `<?php\n` as the `sed` statement works *without* the newline.  But per [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) it looks like I am doing it correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Iterations I've tried:

```
$ find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/\<\?\n/\<\?php\n/g" {} \;

$ find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/<\?\n/<\?php\n/g" {} \;

$ find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/<?\n/<?php\n/g" {} \;

$ find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/<?\n\r/<?php\n/g" {} \;

$ find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/<?\r\n/<?php\n/g" {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed command itself could be something as simple as:

```
sed -i 's/<?$/<?php/'
```

Glue that together with find and it might work for you.

`$` is an anchor matching the end of a line, you might consider using `^` to anchor the match to the beginning as well:

```
s/^<?$/<?php/
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for --> `find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i 's/^<?$/<?php/' {} \;` worked .. Thank you!